# How to list commits for today in SVN using Windows?

Tags: windows, svn

I would like to list the **commits for today** or on a **particular date** in SVN

I see lot of examples for UNIX.

However, I work on **windows** and looking for an equivalent 'date' syntax on windows

```
e.g svn svn diff --summarize 'date /t'
```

I tried the following commands but nothing was displayed.  Not sure what I am doing wrong

Output

```
D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {"2018-10-04"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {2018-10-04}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {2018-10-05}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {2018-10-06}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {2018-10-07}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\nightly_repo\Branches\9-Oct-2018>svn log repo_url/Branches/09-October-2018/ -r {2018-10-08}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use the [Revision Specifiers](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/revs/specifiers/) with the [`DATE /T`](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) command or the `%DATE%` environment variable. However, `DATE /T` and `%DATE%` does not work in my case because the SVN client does not recognize the date format `09-Oct-18` for my locale / regional settings:

```
C:\Users\Pavel.Lyalyakin> svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r {%DATE%}
svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '{09-Oct-18}'
```

That's why I used the `Get-Date` PowerShell cmdlet instead -- it can format the output on the fly.

Here is an example:

`svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r"{$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)}"`

Make sure to read the [Is Subversion a Day Early?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) note in SVNBook.

Comment: Updated my post with output.  Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: What about the output for -r `{2018-10-09}` and -r `{2018-10-10}`?